# What does the > operator do when comparing two C++ containers?

Tags: c++, vector, containers, comparison, standards

For some reason, the ability exists in C++ to do greater-than/less-than comparisons between containers in C++, rather than between container elements. eg.

```
std::vector<int> vec1 = {1, 2, 3}, vec2 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
return vec1 > vec2;
```

The [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) gives the following explanation:

> "true if the contents of the lhs are lexicographically greater than
>   the contents of rhs, false otherwise".

What does "[lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) greater" mean, in this context?
And how is this at all useful?

Comment: See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare

Comment: What do you mean by greater than, the sum of one vector items is greater? or the number of items?

Comment: This is not about the sum. We are looking at whether the sequence will appear before another sequence, just like it would if we were looking at a dictionary.

Comment: You linked to the Wikipedia page yourself, so which part do you not understand?

Comment: @BessieTheCow ... well, for starters, the contents of a vector are not guaranteed to be alphabetical or numerical.
Secondly that page does not address comparisons between sets of different lengths.
You might want to be less unfriendly in future...

Comment: @metamorphosis what does "being alphabetical or numerical" have to do with it? Different length is discussed on that cppreference page.

Comment: I'm not trying to be unfriendly. I just want you to clarify what you do not understand so that your question can be answered better. Otherwise, there's not really anything people can do to answer your question that doesn't just repeat what the cppreference.com article and the Wikipedia page already states. The Wikipedia page does address comparisons between sequences of different lengths. See the paragraph "To compare sequences of different lengths, the shorter sequence is usually padded at the end with enough 'blanks' ... is sometimes called shortlex order."

Comment: The Wikipedia page never suggests that the sequences have to consist of numbers or letters. It uses the word "alphabet" to refer to "a finite set A, ... which is totally ordered." This means the definition works for sequences consisting of any type of elements which has a defined order. The cppreference.com page stated "The comparison is performed by a function equivalent to [`std::lexicographical_compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare)."

Comment: If you read the page on `std::lexicographical_compare`, it states that the elements are compared using `operator<` if no comparison function is specified. It also states "Two ranges are compared element by element," "The first mismatching element defines which range is lexicographically *less* or *greater* than the other," and "If one range is a prefix of another, the shorter range is lexicographically *less* than the other." As far as I can tell, your question is answered by the pages you linked to which is why I'm asking you to clarify specifically which part you're confused about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lexicologically greater would mean the same as in a dictionary. You can visualize it by replacing 1,2,3 with "abc" and 1,2,3,4 with "abcd". The string "abcd" will appear later on in the dictionary because it is lexicologically greater.

If you had 2,2,3 (instead of 1,2,3) because 2 is lexicologically greater than 1, > will return true for the comparison between 2,2,3 and 1,2,3,4.

The relative length of the containers does not matter. We are only looking at whether the sequence will appear in a dictionary before another sequence ('a' appears before 'b', '1' appears before '2').

An example of where this is useful is when you need to know if a sequence comes before another sequence.

Comment: Hi, what does this mean for vectors of non-numerical/alphabetical data?
Thanks for responding.

Comment: Hi, no problem. For vectors of non-numerical data the values will be compared based on their ASCII values but will still follow the same principles that would be followed when comparing numerical values. For example, a vector containing {a,p,p,l,e} will come before a vector containing {o,r,a,n,g,e} because the ASCII value of 'a' precedes the ASCII value of 'o'. I hope that this helps you. Please let me know if I can clarify this further.

Comment: @boyanhristov96 The C++ standard does not require ASCII encoding to be used. A standard-conforming implementation can use an encoding where the letters are not in alphabetical order.

Comment: In other words, it is implementation dependent?

Comment: @boyanhristov96
Hi, if you've got a vector of structs, classes, tuples or anything else that doesn't work. That's what I'm asking about.

Comment: In that case you need to make an operator overload for that container.